# How is a directed simplicial complex definable as a collection of ordered sets?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

Reading [this paper.](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fncom.2017.00048/full) It says that

"An abstract directed simplicial complex is a collection $S$ of finite, ordered sets with the property that if $\sigma \in S$, then every subset $\tau$ of $\sigma$, with the natural ordering inherited from $\sigma$, is also a member of $S$."

If I understand correctly, the elements of the ordered sets are the vertices of the simplices. **But how could an ordering encapsulate all possible ways of directing the edges?**

Take a triangle for example, $ABC$. To say $A<B<C$ could be thought of as directing the edge AB in the direction of A, BC in the direction of B, etc. But how could an ordering describe a directed triangle where one vertex has no edges coming into it? Or no edges going out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy for an ordering to "describe a directed triangle where one vertex has no edges coming into it, or no edges going out of it": if we order $A < B < C$ and have each edge go in the direction of the smaller endpoint, then $A$ has no edges going out of it, and $C$ has no edges coming into it. The thing you can't do with an ordering is create *cycles*: cases where the edges are oriented $A \to B \to C \to A$ or $A \to C \to B \to A$.

The idea (in this paper; I don't know if this usage of directed simplices is conventional) is that a directed simplex is by definition *acyclic*, in which case an ordering suffices.

You can represent any directed graph as a directed simplicial complex by taking each edge to be a $2$-simplex directed in the appropriate direction. So if you wanted a cycle on vertices $A,B,C$, you could have the $2$-simplex $\{A,B\}$ with $A<B$, the $2$-simplex $\{B,C\}$ with $B<C$, and the $2$-simplex $\{C,A\}$ with $C<A$. The inheritance property merely says that $\{A\}$, $\{B\}$, and $\{C\}$ have to be $1$-simplices, and there's nothing nontrivial to say about the ordering there.

In this directed simplicial complex, you *couldn't* add the $3$-simplex $\{A,B,C\}$, because there's no consistent ordering to put on it. Conversely, if your directed simplicial complex contains $\{A,B,C\}$ with $A<B<C$, then it must contain the $2$-simplices $\{A,B\}$ with $A<B$, $\{A,C\}$ with $A<C$, and $\{B,C\}$ with $B<C$, as well as the $1$-simplices $\{A\}$, $\{B\}$, and $\{C\}$.

What I think the authors are doing here when they say things like

> the reconstructions consistently contained directed simplices of dimensions up to $6$ or $7$

is taking a directed graph and constructing the simplicial complex in which every acyclic directed clique is a simplex. This clearly satisfies the definition of a directed simplicial complex: if a set of vertices $\sigma$ induces an acyclic directed clique, and $\tau \subset \sigma$, then $\tau$ also induces an acyclic directed clique.

Comment: The reason simplicial complexes are defined this way is because they're only interested in complexes made up of simplices with one source and one sink - these directed graphs have the maximal directionality of any directed graph on the same number of vertices. Directionality is the sum of squares of the signed degree of each vertex.

Comment: It does make sense. I'd feel better about the terminology if they called it something like "the diclique complex of a graph" (by analogy with things like the [clique complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_complex)) to avoid hiding the step where we take a graph *and* a particular kind of structure we're interested in, and build the simplicial complex of those structures.

Comment: Not sure whether or not this is worthy of being a separate question since it seems like you'd be able to answer it. In S 4.1.3 the authors say "The directed simplicial complex associated to a directed graph G is called the directed flag complex of G." My confusion is that the algorithm they produce is for finding the flag complex of the graph from a Hasse diagram. But in S 2.2.1 of the supplementary materials they explain that the Hasse diagram is obtained from a directed simplicial complex. So what's being accomplished by going from complex to hasse diagram back to complex?

Comment: I think the idea is they first encode the graph as a Hasse diagram (though I don't quite see how), and then convert the Hasse diagram of the graph to the Hasse diagram of the directed flag complex using the algorithm in 2.2.1; then, if you want, you can get out the flag complex from the resulting Hasse diagram.

Comment: They give a detailed procedure of how to encode the directed simplicial complex of a directed graph as a Hasse diagram, so I would think that you would first have to convert your graph in to a simplicial complex...

Comment: Maybe you first take the trivial directed simplicial complex consisting of only the 2-simplices (the edges)?

Comment: That would make sense (kind of) but I don't see it stated explicitly anywhere so I'm going to ask aonther question about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66602/discussion-between-eben-cowley-and-misha-lavrov).